# VB Clear Scripting.Dictionary object

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing an **Excel macro**, and I'm having trouble clearing a **Scripting.Dictionary object**:

```
Dim test As Integer
test = CompListDict.Count
CompListDict.RemoveAll
Set CompListDict = Nothing
Set CompListDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim test1 As Integer
test1 = CompListDict.Count
```

Before I do this, I add items to the dictionary, and then i try to clear it, but test1 will equal test and equal the nr of objects I've added.

What am I doing wrong ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I run the following macro on my workstation, it works :

```
        Set compListDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        compListDict.Add 1, "Test"

        Dim test As Integer
        test = compListDict.Count
        compListDict.RemoveAll

        Set compListDict = Nothing
        Set compListDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        Dim test1 As Integer
        test1 = compListDict.Count
```

After running it, test1 equals 0, and test equals 1.

Make sure you have Option Explicit enabled, and that you don't have any typos in your variable names.

Also, make sure you don't have an "On Error Resume Next" statement, as it will hide away errors in your code. Try placing "On Error Goto 0" before your code snippet, so that Excel will display any error message.

Since you're setting the variable value to Nothing, and assigning it a new dictionnary object, it should be impossible that it retains the previsouly stored values.

I also tried running the following code, and it also gives the same results:

```
        Set compListDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        compListDict.Add 1, "Test"

        Dim test As Integer
        test = compListDict.Count
        compListDict.RemoveAll

        Dim test1 As Integer
        test1 = compListDict.Count
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: It is really crazy, but for me it does not work. Maybe now Scripting.Dictionary is long ago forgotten and not used type. It magically stores 1 key (other keys and all the values are removed) even after =Nothing, CreateObject(), and RemoveAll...... Maybe starting Excel again will help, but I just cannot rely on this. I will switch to collection

Answer (score 5):

Your code looks ok although the 2 lines where you set your dict to nothing and recreate it are not necessary.

Not sure if it's related but there is a bug in some versions of VBA IDE: if you have added a watch on `dict(aKeyThatDoesNotExist)` it can lead to tgat key being added to the dict and not being removable. the only solution I know: restart Excel to clear the memory.

**EDIT**

For Siddharth:
Tested with Excel 2003 & 2010.

Create a new book.
Open VBA IDE.
Type this in the Sheet1 module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim d As Variant
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    d.Add "a", "a"
    Debug.Print d.Count

    'Add watch here on d and d("b")

    Debug.Print d.Count

End Sub
```

Run it in step by step mode and when on the commented line, add a watch on `d` and `d("b")`.
The second `Debug.Print` will print 2. So far, you could think that the watch created an entry, which is weird because you would not expect watch to have side effects.

Run the macro again: the **first** `Debug.Print` will print 2 and you will notice that the dictionary already has a "b" key.

Actually, contrary to what I said above, removing the watch on `d("b")` and rerunning the macro will reset the dictionary properly.

Comment: Hmmm that is interesting. Can you reproduce it or is it a random thing?

Comment: Thanks will look into it today :) And If I am able to reproduce it then I will file this bug with MS today :)

Comment: Hmmm, I added a watch on "d" but still got "1" from both debug prints. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need a watch on `d("b")` for example, where `"b"` is a key that has not been added to the dictionary before.

Comment: @SiddharthRout After [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296522/looping-through-a-scripting-dictionary-using-index-item-number/11296723#comment14862366_11296723) I believe this behaviour is due to the fact that `d("b")` is a shortcut for `d.Item("b")` which does create a new key if it did not already exist. It is just weird that the debugger watch window has side effects on the actual variables but I can see why now.

Comment: Aha! a blast from the past :) I almost forgot about this one. Never got down to testing it after that. Will do it probably later tonight.

Comment: I had this exact issue where the watch had added an extra item to my dictionary, causing my for loop to fail, thanks for the explanation