# Looping through a Scripting.Dictionary using index/item number

Tags: vba, dictionary

Similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9836919/698590), when using a `Scripting.Dictionary` object in VBA, the outcome of the code below is unexpected.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim d As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim s As String
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    d.Add "a", "a"
    Debug.Print d.Count ' Prints '1' as expected

    For i = 1 To d.Count
        s = d.Item(i)
        Debug.Print s ' Prints ' ' (null) instead of 'a'
    Next i

    Debug.Print d.Count ' Prints '2' instead of '1'

End Sub
```

Using a zero-based index, the same outcome is achieved:

```
For i = 0 To d.Count - 1
    s = d.Item(i)
    Debug.Print s
Next i
```

Watching the object, I can actually see that it has two items, the key for the newly added is `1`, as added from `i`. If I increase this loop to a higher number, then the number of items in the dictionary is increased, once for each loop.

*I have tested this in Office/VBA 2003, 2010, and 2013. All exhibit the same behavior, and I expect other versions (2007) will as well.*

I can work around this with other looping methods, but this caught me off guard when I was trying to store objects and was getting an **object expected error** on the `s = d.Item(i)` line.

For the record, I know that I can do things like this:

```
For Each v In d.Keys
    Set o = d.item(v)
Next v
```

But I'm more curious about why I can't seem to iterate through the items by number.

Comment: @assylias I do see that in the documentation `.Item(Key)` but I also see `.Key(Key)`, though I'm not sure how to use the `Key` method... Is there a way to iterate by item number?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According to [the documentation of the `Item` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84k9x471%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

> Sets or returns an item for a specified key in a Dictionary object.

In your case, you don't have an item whose key is `1` so doing:

```
s = d.Item(i)
```

actually creates a new key / value pair in your dictionary, and the value is empty because you have not used the optional `newItem` argument.

The Dictionary also has the [`Items` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aet97f2%28v=vs.84%29) which allows looping over the indices:

```
a = d.Items
For i = 0 To d.Count - 1
    s = a(i)
Next i
```

Comment: I follow that, but is there no way, then, to iterate/read by index/item number? *Seems like a silly implementation, if you ask me. ;-)*

Comment: And with this info, I've changed the question to not include 'bug' wording.

Answer (score 39):

Adding to assylias's answer - assylias shows us D.ITEMS is a method that returns an array. Knowing that, we don't need the variant array a(i) [See caveat below].  We just need to use the proper array syntax.

```
For i = 0 To d.Count - 1
    s = d.Items()(i)
    Debug.Print s
Next i()
```

KEYS works the same way

```
For i = 0 To d.Count - 1
    Debug.Print d.Keys()(i), d.Items()(i)
Next i
```

This syntax is also useful for the SPLIT function which may help make this clearer.  SPLIT also returns an array with lower bounds at 0. Thus, the following prints "C".

```
Debug.Print Split("A,B,C,D", ",")(2)
```

SPLIT is a function.  Its parameters are in the first set of parentheses.  Methods and Functions always use the first set of parentheses for parameters, even if no parameters are needed. In the example SPLIT returns the array {"A","B","C","D"}.  Since it returns an array we can use a second set of parentheses to identify an element within the returned array just as we would any array.

**Caveat**: This shorter syntax may not be as efficient as using the variant array a() when iterating through the entire dictionary since the shorter syntax invokes the dictionary's Items method with each iteration. The shorter syntax is best for plucking a single item by number from a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Using `d.Keys()(i)` method is a very bad idea, because on each call it will re-create a new array (you will have significant speed reduction).

Here is an analogue of `Scripting.Dictionary` called "Hash Table" class from @TheTrick, that support such enumerator: http://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/354370/blog2905.html

```
Dim oDict As clsTrickHashTable

Sub aaa()
    Set oDict = New clsTrickHashTable

    oDict.Add "a", "aaa"
    oDict.Add "b", "bbb"

    For i = 0 To oDict.Count - 1
        Debug.Print oDict.Keys(i) & " - " & oDict.Items(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code from Craig Hatmaker to change a value in the dictionary d by looping through index i. `d.Items(i) = s` doesn'work. But `d.Item(d.Keys(i)) = s` worked. In other words: You need to workaround by getting the key by index and with the key you can access the item.
Pay attention that I tried Items() with s first and then Item(Keys) without s.
Not sure if this is good programming and works in every case, but maybe it could help someone.